# Java/Android "promises" implementation with chaining and joining?

Tags: java, android, promise

I'm looking for a Java/Android implementation of promises that allow **chaining** and **joining**.

With **chaining** I mean chaining `then` calls so code looks like synchronous.

```
// Example:
getCity().then(getRestaurants).then(findBestMenu);
```

With **joining** I mean waiting for multiple promises to be fulfilled, or any of them fail.

```
// Example:
Promise p1 = getFlights();
Promise p2 = getHotels();
PromiseManager.when(p1,p2).then(planTrip).fail(stayAtHome);
```

I have found these solutions:

[RxJava-Promises](https://github.com/darylteo/rxjava-promises/tree/master/rxjava-promises) supports chaining via `PromiseFunction` and `RepromiseFunction`.

[jdeferred](https://github.com/jdeferred/jdeferred) supports joining via `DeferredManager`. **EDIT**: It also supports chaining via `DonePipe`.

**EDIT2:**

[RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) are for reactive paradigm. A bit more complex but powerful.

Comment: I use this one: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Comment: Is your question asking to us find other libraries that provide promise support? Because that's off topic.

Comment: I was looking for a promises lib with chaining/piping and joining/manager. I see jdeferred and bolts have those features.